# Javascript - Create Nested Array of Objects From Two Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Trying to create a single combined array of objects from two arrays:

```
let versions = [
          {
            version: "1609936394",
          },
          {
            version: "1609936409",
          }
]
```

and

```
let devices = [
  {
    download_device: "Box 1",
  },
  {
    download_device: "Box 2",
  },
  {
    download_device: "Box 3",
  },
  {
    download_device: "Box 4",
  }
]
```

The outcome I'm trying to achieve, albeit unsuccessfully, is having a separate entry for each download_device and version number combination, ie.

```
[
    {
        download_device: "Box 1",
        version: "1609936394"
    },
    {
        download_device: "Box 2",
        version: "1609936394"
    },
    {
        download_device: "Box 3",
        version: "1609936394"
    },
    {
        download_device: "Box 4",
        version: "1609936394"
    },
    {
        download_device: "Box 1",
        version: "1609936409"
    }...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My current solution (only outputs the first version number):

```
let data = devices.map((d, index) => {
                       versions.map((v, i) => {
                         v.device = devices[index].download_device,
                         d.version = versions[index].version
                         return v;
                       })
                     return d;
                })
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) (or a "JSON array"). Those are all arrays of objects.

Comment: Can you also provide your attempt(s) (even if they were unsuccessful?)

Comment: @NickParsons Have added my current attempt to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with your approach is that you're trying to access invalid indexes. As your `devices` array is longer than your `versions` array, you will reach indexes which don't exist within your `versions` array, causing an issue when you try and access a property on an index that doesn't exist.

Instead, you can map over your `versions` array, and for each version map over your devices array (as you want to add the version to all devices). When you map over your devices, you can grab the properties from each device, and spread them into a new object (`...obj`) using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). In this new object, you can also add the current `version` property. Since the inner `.map()` will return an array, you can change the outer `.map()` method to a [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) which will flatten each array returned from the callback into one larger array result:

```js
const versions = [ { version: "1609936394", }, { version: "1609936409", } ];
const devices = [ { download_device: "Box 1", }, { download_device: "Box 2", }, { download_device: "Box 3", }, { download_device: "Box 4", } ];

const res = versions.flatMap(({version}) => devices.map(obj => ({...obj, version})));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Build all combinations by first iterate over versions and inside version at each entry iterate over your devices.

build a new Object Literal and push that Object literal to a result array.

```js
let versions = [{
    version: "1609936394",
  },
  {
    version: "1609936409",
  }
]


let devices = [{
    download_device: "Box 1",
  },
  {
    download_device: "Box 2",
  },
  {
    download_device: "Box 3",
  },
  {
    download_device: "Box 4",
  }
]

let res = [];
versions.forEach((x) => {
  devices.forEach((y) => {
    let obj = {
      "version": x.version,
      "download_device": y.download_device
    };
    res.push(obj);
  });
})

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two arrays of objects. To create a single array that has each element of one with every element in the other.

A general solution that doesn't care about property names iterates over one array and creates copies of the other and combines the properties, e.g.:

```js
let versions = [
  {version: "1609936394"},
  {version: "1609936409"}
];
let devices = [
  {download_device: "Box 1"},
  {download_device: "Box 2"},
  {download_device: "Box 3"},
  {download_device: "Box 4"}
]

// Step by step version
let result1 = versions.reduce((acc, ver) => {
  devices.forEach(device => {
    // Shallow copy device
    let o = {...device};
    // Shallow copy ver onto o
    Object.assign(o, ver);
    // Add to accumulator
    acc.push(o);
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result1);

// Concise version
let result2 = versions.reduce((acc, ver) => (
  devices.forEach(device => acc.push({...device, ...ver})
), acc), []);

console.log(result2);
```

Note these are shallow copies, and duplicate properties between the objects being combined aren't handled.